# Flask-security: allow first name and last name fields

Tags: python, flask

using the flask security library how do I also allow first name and last name input in the register form? the website doesn't have much information using flask-security but only has info regarding flask-login.

Comment: Have you read the [Customizing Views](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html) section of the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement you own login form and view. From flask_security's documentation( https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html) :

Forms

All forms can be overridden. For each form used, you can specify a replacement class. This allows you to add extra fields to the register form or override validators:

```
from flask_security.forms import RegisterForm
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = TextField('First Name', [Required()])
    last_name = TextField('Last Name', [Required()])
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm)
```